# Selenium FindBy anotations in abstract class

Tags: java, selenium, abstract-class

I'm working on test automation framework in Selenium for Java. I have situation where there will be different pages sharing very similar functionalities. I came up with idea to create abstract class with some common implementation like below:

```
abstract class Foo{

    // this is the problem, how to annotate below elements?
    // at this point there is now way to know "how" and "using"
    // @FindBy(how = ???, using = ???)
    private WebElement element1;
    // @FindBy(how = ???, using = ???)
    private WebElement element2;

    public void setElement1(String v){
        this.element1.sendKeys(v);
    }

    public void clickElement2(){
        this.element2.submit()
    }
}

public class Bar extends Foo{
    ...
}

public class Baz extends Foo{
    ...
}
```

I would like to avoid implementing same structure for each and every page. is there a clever way to do that? I'm a very beginner in Java. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what the similarities are?  Is the HTML similar?  Do they have pieces that are identical, and others that aren't?

Comment: Type of elements is the same. Like both pages have 4 text fields, 2 buttons. In general I can't assume about its id or name. I wanted to abstract this, but it seems it makes more problems then provides benefit.

Comment: If there is any HTML that is the same, identify what is the same and what isn't.  For example, if the text fields were both in a wrapper element with an ID/class of "fields" then you could build a common selector.  The only reason you would want to extend is if a page has common selectors.  If you there aren't then there's no reason to extend.

Answer (score 0):

If your pages don't share common elements, this setup does not make sense. Rather create a helper class to do the method logic for you where you will pass in the `WebElement`s. Something along the lines of:

Your classes representing pages/vies:

```
public class Bar {

    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "myIdForElement1")
    private WebElement element1;

}

public class Baz {

    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "myIdForElement2")
    private WebElement element2;

}
```

Your util class:

```
public class SeleniumUtil {

    public static void setElement1(WebElement el, String value){
        el.sendKeys(value);
    }

}
```

Comment: @MrTi I agree for something as simple as sendKeys(). Though I meant it more as a way to show how you can separate your classes and logic to avoid the abstract setup.